# Why this PayPal daily recurring subscription doesn't process the next payment?

Tags: forms, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'm testing PayPal Standard using PayPal Sandbox.

When I pay, PayPal creates a new subscription profile and charges me the first money. Everything is correct.
It's a $20 daily billing cycle, so the next day, it should charge me $20 at the same hour. Instead, it does nothing.

Today it's November 21th and in the PayPal account the subscription panel still says "next payment: November 20th". I have $9999 on Merchant and Client account too.

Should I edit my form code?

Here is the button code:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@myemail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="67;2;33789261736f93677856cfe698a9c9ca">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="MENSILE (7b3e99ef1fb567b0151b1cbd8ec24627)">
    <input type="hidden" name="max_text" value="Fino a 35 feeds differenti|Twitter, Linkedin e Facebook|Aggiornamenti software|Rinnovo automatico mensile|Supporto Email">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="00001">
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="20.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="D">
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="page_style" value="SOCIAL">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.mywebsite.com/members/site/ipn">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mywebsite.com/members/user/site/pricing/success?67;2;33789261736f93677856cfe698a9c9ca">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.mywebsite.com/members/user/site/pricing">
    <input type="image" style="width:200px;" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-635" src="/members/themes/classic/images/subscriptions/buy2.png" border="0" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: For recurring payments , it can take up to 24 hrs for the profile to charge. Usually setting the start date on the same day that the profile is created can charge the profile on the same day but the built in logic is that it can take up to 24 hrs for the charge to complete.

Comment: 3 days later: today it's November 23th and nothing happened.

Comment: please verify all the variables added in the form https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI00JQU